# Shell script execute permission not preserved on Windows VM guest in Cygwin

Tags: windows-7, linux, permissions, cygwin, vmware

I have a Ubuntu machine that is running a windows 7 VM. I am using VMware workstation 15 pro. My home directory is shared with the VM and is mapped as a network drive on the Windows guest.

I have a script that I want to run using Cygwin on Windows guest. On Linux the permissions are `rwxr-xr-x`. However, in Cygwin on the Windows guest the permissions are `rw-r--r--`. I am loosing my execute permission. From Cygwin if I chmod the file to add execute permission (eg: `chmod u+x foo.sh`) there is no change. How can I add execute permission in the windows guest? Is this an issue with the VMWare share, or is it an issue with network shares in general?

The shell script starts with `#!`, so by default cygwin *should* treat it as executable if this were a local file. According to the [cygwin manual](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-filemodes.html) if this were an NFS share it should *just work*. I am not sure if the issue is that this looks like SMB, or if it is a deeper issue with the way VMWare shares files.

Comment: Are you using VMware shared folders or are you actually mounting your home directory as a network share (i.e. CIFS/SMB)?

Comment: It seems that the mount has the permission for execution disabled. Has Cygwin has no mount capabilities you should check the "security" settings/policy of Windows

Comment: @jamesdlin It is a VMware shared folder. But on a windows guest it looks like a Windows/SMB network share, and I ticked the box to make it look like a network drive that is mounted on boot. I didn't actually set up a network share on the host.